# Understanding Text feature extraction TfidfVectorizer in python scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Reading the documentation for text feature extraction in scikit-learn, I am not sure how the different arguments available  for TfidfVectorizer (and may be other vectorizers) affect the outcome.

Here are the arguments I am not sure how they work:

```
TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',  ngram_range=(1, 2), max_df=0.5, min_df=20, use_idf=True)
```

The documentation is clear on the use of stop_words/ max_df (both have similar effect and may be one can be used instead of the other). However, I am not sure if these options should be used together with ngrams. Which one occurs/handled first, ngrams or stop_words? why? Based on my experiment, stop words are removed first, but the purpose of ngrams is to extract phrases, etc. I am not sure about the effect of this sequence (Stops removed and then ngramed).

Second, does it make sense to use max_df/min_df arguments together with use_idf argument? aren't the purpose of these similar?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I see several questions in this post.

> 1. How do the different arguments in TfidfVectorizer interact with one another?

You really have to use it quite a bit to develop a sense of intuition (has been my experience anyway).

TfidfVectorizer is a bag of words approach. In NLP, sequences of words and their window is important; this kind of destroys some of that context.

**How do I control what tokens get outputted?**

Set `ngram_range` to (1,1) for outputting only one-word tokens, (1,2) for one-word and two-word tokens, (2, 3) for two-word and three-word tokens, etc.

`ngram_range` works hand-in-hand with `analyzer`. Set `analyzer` to "word" for outputting words and phrases, or set it to "char" to output character ngrams.

If you want your output to have both "word" and "char" features, use sklearn's FeatureUnion. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46926863/1577947).

**How do I remove unwanted stuff?**

Use `stop_words` to remove less-meaningful english words.

The list of stop words that sklearn uses can be found at:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.stop_words import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS
```

The logic of removing stop words has to do with the fact that these words don't carry a lot of meaning, and they appear a lot in most text:

```
[('the', 79808),
 ('of', 40024),
 ('and', 38311),
 ('to', 28765),
 ('in', 22020),
 ('a', 21124),
 ('that', 12512),
 ('he', 12401),
 ('was', 11410),
 ('it', 10681),
 ('his', 10034),
 ('is', 9773),
 ('with', 9739),
 ('as', 8064),
 ('i', 7679),
 ('had', 7383),
 ('for', 6938),
 ('at', 6789),
 ('by', 6735),
 ('on', 6639)]
```

Since stop words generally have a high frequency, it might make sense to use `max_df` as a float of say 0.95 to remove the top 5% but then you're assuming that the top 5% is all stop words which might not be the case. It really depends on your text data. In my line of work, it's very common that the top words or phrases are NOT stop words because I work with dense text (search query data) in very specific topics.

Use `min_df` as an integer to remove rare-occurring words. If they only occur once or twice, they won't add much value and are usually really obscure. Furthermore, there's generally a lot of them so ignoring them with say `min_df=5` can greatly reduce your memory consumption and data size.

**How do I Include stuff that's being stripped out?**

`token_pattern` uses a regex pattern `\b\w\w+\b` which means that tokens have to be at least 2 characters long so words like "I", "a" are removed and also numbers like 0 - 9 are removed. You'll also notice it removes apostrophes

> 2. What happens first, ngram generation or stop word removal?

Let's do a little test.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.stop_words import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS

docs = np.array(['what is tfidf',
        'what does tfidf stand for',
        'what is tfidf and what does it stand for',
        'tfidf is what',
        "why don't I use tfidf",
        '1 in 10 people use tfidf'])

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False, norm=None, ngram_range=(1, 1))
matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(docs).toarray()

df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, index=docs, columns=tfidf.get_feature_names())

for doc in docs:
    print(' '.join(word for word in doc.split() if word not in ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS))
```

This prints out:

```
tfidf
does tfidf stand
tfidf does stand
tfidf
don't I use tfidf
1 10 people use tfidf
```

Now let's print df:

```
                                           10  and  does  don  for   in   is  \
what is tfidf                             0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0   
what does tfidf stand for                 0.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0   
what is tfidf and what does it stand for  0.0  1.0   1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0   
tfidf is what                             0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0   
why don't I use tfidf                     0.0  0.0   0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
1 in 10 people use tfidf                  1.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0   

                                           it  people  stand  tfidf  use  \
what is tfidf                             0.0     0.0    0.0    1.0  0.0   
what does tfidf stand for                 0.0     0.0    1.0    1.0  0.0   
what is tfidf and what does it stand for  1.0     0.0    1.0    1.0  0.0   
tfidf is what                             0.0     0.0    0.0    1.0  0.0   
why don't I use tfidf                     0.0     0.0    0.0    1.0  1.0   
1 in 10 people use tfidf                  0.0     1.0    0.0    1.0  1.0   

                                          what  why  
what is tfidf                              1.0  0.0  
what does tfidf stand for                  1.0  0.0  
what is tfidf and what does it stand for   2.0  0.0  
tfidf is what                              1.0  0.0  
why don't I use tfidf                      0.0  1.0  
1 in 10 people use tfidf                   0.0  0.0
```

Notes:

- `use_idf=False, norm=None` when these are set, it's equivalent to using sklearn's CountVectorizer. It will just return counts.
- Notice the word "don't" was converted to "don". This is where you'd change `token_pattern` to something like `token_pattern=r"\b\w[\w']+\b"` to include apostrophes.
- we see a lot of stop words

Let's remove stopwords and look at df again:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False, norm=None, stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1, 2))
```

Outputs:

```
                                           10  10 people  does  does stand  \
what is tfidf                             0.0        0.0   0.0         0.0   
what does tfidf stand for                 0.0        0.0   1.0         0.0   
what is tfidf and what does it stand for  0.0        0.0   1.0         1.0   
tfidf is what                             0.0        0.0   0.0         0.0   
why don't I use tfidf                     0.0        0.0   0.0         0.0   
1 in 10 people use tfidf                  1.0        1.0   0.0         0.0   

                                          does tfidf  don  don use  people  \
what is tfidf                                    0.0  0.0      0.0     0.0   
what does tfidf stand for                        1.0  0.0      0.0     0.0   
what is tfidf and what does it stand for         0.0  0.0      0.0     0.0   
tfidf is what                                    0.0  0.0      0.0     0.0   
why don't I use tfidf                            0.0  1.0      1.0     0.0   
1 in 10 people use tfidf                         0.0  0.0      0.0     1.0   

                                          people use  stand  tfidf  \
what is tfidf                                    0.0    0.0    1.0   
what does tfidf stand for                        0.0    1.0    1.0   
what is tfidf and what does it stand for         0.0    1.0    1.0   
tfidf is what                                    0.0    0.0    1.0   
why don't I use tfidf                            0.0    0.0    1.0   
1 in 10 people use tfidf                         1.0    0.0    1.0   

                                          tfidf does  tfidf stand  use  \
what is tfidf                                    0.0          0.0  0.0   
what does tfidf stand for                        0.0          1.0  0.0   
what is tfidf and what does it stand for         1.0          0.0  0.0   
tfidf is what                                    0.0          0.0  0.0   
why don't I use tfidf                            0.0          0.0  1.0   
1 in 10 people use tfidf                         0.0          0.0  1.0   

                                          use tfidf  
what is tfidf                                   0.0  
what does tfidf stand for                       0.0  
what is tfidf and what does it stand for        0.0  
tfidf is what                                   0.0  
why don't I use tfidf                           1.0  
1 in 10 people use tfidf                        1.0
```

Take-aways:

- the token "don use" happened because `don't I use` had the `'t` stripped off and because `I` was less than two characters, it was removed so the words were joined to `don use`... which actually wasn't the structure and could potentially change the structure a bit!
- **Answer: stop words are removed, short characters are removed, then ngrams are generated which can return unexpected results.**

> 3. does it make sense to use max_df/min_df arguments together with use_idf argument?

My opinion, the whole point of term-frequency inverse document frequency is to allow re-weighting of the highly frequent words (words that would appear a the top of a sorted frequency list). This re-weighting will take the highest frequency ngrams and move them down the list to a lower position. Therefore, it's supposed to handle `max_df` scenarios.

Maybe it's more of a personal choice whether you want to move them down the list ("re-weight" / de-prioritize them) or remove them completely.

I use `min_df` a lot and it makes sense to use `min_df` if you're working with a huge dataset because rare words won't add value and will just cause a lot of processing issues. I don't use `max_df` much but I'm sure there are scenarios when working with data like all of Wikipedia that this might make sense to remove the top x%.

Answer (score 1):

1. The stop word removal will not affect your ngrams. A vocabulary (tokens) list is first created according to your tokenizer and ngram range, then stop words are removed from this list (so only unigrams will be affected as the stop word list contains ungrams only). Note that it is not the same if you remove the stop words in the tokenization step (what people often do), then they won't be included in the bigrams either.
2. Using min_df may in fact counter the effect of tf idf as a word that    appeared maybe twice in only one document will have a high score    (remember scores are for a document). It depends on the application    of your system (information retrieval/ text categorization). If the    threshold is low, it shouldn't affect a lot text classification, but     retrieval might be biased (what if I want to find documents with    "Spain" and it only appears once, in one document, in the entire    collection?). Max_df is affected thanks to use_idf as you said, but if you remove the word from vocabulary it might have an stronger impact than only weighting it low. It depends again on what you plan to do with the weights.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Elliot, thank you much for the response. Please see Jarad's response below re order of stop_words and ngrams. based on my experiment, I see that stop_words are removed first, too. But what you write above is interesting and ideal - tokens are created according to tokenizer... Is it possible to show an example?

Comment: Yes ! my bad then, Jarad showed that my thought was in fact wrong, and glad to know it know. In fact, I rarely use stop words removal with scikit `Vectorizer`. I create my own tokenizer  and keep/remove the patterns I'm interested in, inside the function. What kind of example would you like ?

Comment: I was wondering if what you said, create ngrams and then remove stop words is possible as the code is written now. Thinking more about it, it should not make a difference. thanks